# If you have two clocks moving toward each other and they both stop when they meet does it point to a paradox?

Tags: special-relativity

Say they both decelerate at the same rate also. If clock A sees clock B as slower than itself and clock B see clock  A as slower than itself due to relativity isn't this a paradox because when they meet (as far as my understanding is concerned) they will each see the other as being slower? Obviously I am missing something here but I do not know what.

Comment: When they meet they are no longer moving relative to each other. So they do not see each other as being slower in that moment. Am I misunderstanding your question? Otherwise if you're asking about the two seeing eachother as slower while they are still moving toward eachother, this is just the "twin paradox" and I think this video explains the resolution very well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8GqaAp3cGs

Comment: Yes I think you might be misunderstanding my question. My question is about how do the clocks go from being vastly different from each other to the same. The twin paradox doesn't answer it either because in this thought experiment they both slowdown at the same rate.

Comment: The time dilation is a function of velocity $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$. So as $v$ decreases  continuously the time dilation factor decreases continuously. It does not suddenly change from being vastly different to the same. Or are you talking about the total time elapsed on either clock and not the rate at which the clocks change? I suspect I'm still not understanding your question. Just trying to clarify.

Comment: @AXensen yes I am talking about the total time elapsed on either clock

Comment: Ah okay finally I understand what the question is and why one might think this was a paradox. Might I suggest editing the question to clarify? The resolution is this - both observers will see the other one's clock as being behind theirs (as in they visually see an earlier time on the others' clock), but they see the clock hands of the others' clock moving faster than 1 second per second. By the time they meet, the clocks read the same time. If that isn't obvious to you - if you think they see each other's clocks as moving slower, then you should indeed watch the video about the twin paradox.

Comment: This is not a general relativity question

Comment: I found this video debunking the [twin paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgvajuvSpF4)

Comment: You can find a video to tell you anything you want!  In any case, it is not a "debunking", he even briefly "resolves" it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it helpful to consider the Doppler effect. Imagine two police cars approaching head on. The occupants in each car will hear the siren of the other car as going faster than their own, owing to the Doppler effect, but when they come to a halt and meet the sirens will sound the same. Something similar happens with the approaching clocks. When they meet, they will be ticking at the same rate.

Assuming the set-up was properly symmetrical, the elapsed times on the clocks would also agree. Let's suppose the clocks were travelling at such a speed that each thought the other was time dilated by 50%, and when they meet each clock shows 10 hours since the start of their journey. You will ask yourself, how can they both show the same time if each thought the other was running at half speed? The answer is that they disagree on when their respective journeys started. In the frame of each clock, the clock's journey started ten hours ago while the other clock's journey started 20 hours ago. All the main effects of SR, such as time dilation and length contraction, boil down to a lack of synchronisation at a distance.

Comment: "the other clock's journey started 20 hours ago" is a very unclear statement. Visually, clock 1 won't see light indicating that clock 2 has started its journey until after it starts its own journey. Visually, clock 1 will see clock 2's hands moving faster than 1 second per second because they are moving toward eachother. You have to use a very odd coordinate system for this to be true - perhaps you could clarify what the meaning of this sentence is.

Comment: @AXensen where did I mention what either clock could see? If two inertially-moving clocks A and B meet head-on at time T, each showing 10 hours of elapsed time, and if the relative speed of the clocks is such that each was time dilated by 50% in the frame of the other, then Clock A would have registered 0 hours at a time T-20 in the frame of Clock B, and Clock B would have registered 0 hours at a time T-20 in the frame of Clock A.

Comment: I see now you're just using the standard coordinate frame conversion. I'm not saying you mentioned what either clock could see. I guess my contention is that I've always found the coordinate frame conversation to be a poor way of communicating what's going on in the twin paradox. It leads people to not understand that the twins see eachother as being slowed down by more than $\gamma$ while moving apart, and actually sped up, not slowed down, when moving back together. But I can also see that I'm being a bit obtuse, and that this is a standard way of analyzing the situation.

Answer (score -1):

In a lot of popular descriptions of the twin's paradox, they will use a dialogue that goes something like this. "Observer A sees B's clock tick slower, and B sees A's clock tick slower? Which one is right? It turns out they are both right!" I would argue, they are both wrong!

They both must be ticking at the same rate and the elapsed times are equal when they meet. The problem is, when they use the Lorentz transformation, there is a not meaningful comparison of clock rates. It is a bit like two observers that are some distance apart comparing their ruler sizes optically. They think the other's ruler is shorter, but when they bring them together, they are the same size. However, this does not mean time dilation is an illusion and the twin's paradox demonstrates two travelers can have different elapsed times and that time dilation can have real consequences. How is this resolved? The answer is to sum up and compare the spacetime intervals of the moving clocks. All observers will then agree on which clock has the greatest elapsed time.

This is a bit like drawing two routes on a map and measuring which path is the longest. To sum up path segments on an x,y map you can calculate the Pythagorean distance of each segment using $\sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}$. In relativity, time does not add up in the same way as spatial distances, and we have to use $\sqrt{\Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2/c^2}$ to calculate the invariant spacetime interval of each segment. In your example, the spacetime intervals are identical, so the elapsed proper times are identical, and this will be true from any observer's point of view.

Trying to compare elapsed times of two spatially separated clocks that have relative motion using the time dilation equation instead of the spacetime interval, is like trying to compare the lengths of two rods in a photograph when one rod is near the camera and the other is far away. Best to always use the spacetime interval.